# Capture Cell range from user input in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I receive excel workbooks from various customers containing lists of employees with gender and date of birth columns.  They arrive in varying formats. I am creating an excel worksheet that I will add to each of these workbooks which will allow me to apply a series of formulas to the customer data. The problem is that I do not know the location of the date of birth data in advance.

I want a macro to prompt me to select the range for the date of birth values and then place that data range into a cell (F31) on my worksheet so that I can pull it into my other formulas.

The code I created below works, but it does not pull the worksheet tab name along with the range. How can I get the worksheet name along with the cell range?

```
Sub ChooseDOBRange()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
    rng.Copy

    Worksheets("COVER SHEET").Range("F31") = rng.Address    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get the worksheet name along with the cell range?

You need `rng.Parent.Name`

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub ChooseDOBRange()
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error Resume Next '<~~ In case user presses Cancel
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Copy

        Worksheets("COVER SHEET").Range("F31").Value = _
        rng.Parent.Name & " - " & rng.Address '<~~ Something like "Sheet2 - $C$6:$H$14"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I assumed OP wanted a valid range to use with `INDIRECT` or such.  Either way, we're on the same page with `Range.Parent.Name`.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to get this depending on whether or not you want the `Workbook` name to be in the formula also.  I am testing these in the Immediate Window.

**Method 1** uses `.Address` with the `External` parameter set to `True`

```
?ActiveCell.Address(,,,True)
```

> [Book2]Sheet1!$A$1

**Method 2** uses the `.Address` along with the sheet name from `Range.Parent.Name` where `Parent` refers to the `Worksheet` for a `Range`

```
?"'" & ActiveCell.Parent.Name & "'!" & ActiveCell.Address
```

> 'Sheet1'!$A$1

Comment: ++ for going the extra mile :)

Comment: Excellent! I used Siddharths code and changed it to DOBrng.Parent.Name & "!" & DOBrng.Address so I could store the proper syntax to use with INDIRECT. It works fine except when I choose a set of ranges that are not contiguous. In that case the worksheet name is not appended to the cell range properly it only appends to the beginning of the string: Sheet2!$C$17:$C$21,$C$24:$C$26 when instead I need it to be Sheet2!$C$17:$C$21,Sheet2!$C$24:$C$26. Any thoughts on how to make it work in that situation?

Comment: `INDIRECT` does not support discontinuous ranges so you need a different approach.  You could iterate through `rng.Areas` and spit out each area address into its own cell.  You could then combine them with an `INDIRECT` for each area.  Best approach really depends on the function you are using around `INDIRECT`.